# SSO implementation in IOS with ws02 identity server

Tags: ios, amazon-ec2, wso2, single-sign-on, wso2-identity-server

I am trying to add SSO feature(testing with google oauth) for my iOS application our backend is implemented with WS02 identity server .
For that i have followed this tutorial .
http://wso2.com/library/articles/2014/07/sso-for-native-mobile-applications-with-wso2-identity-server/

Though the tutorial is written for android the same guidance could be used with the help of iOS sample code from WS02 
[Code sample to be followed for both platform](https://github.com/wso2/carbon-identity/tree/master/components/agents/mobile-proxy-idp)

Problem statement :
The very first step to authorize the app is failing 
with error saying unable to find the app with this client id [image: See this image for error info].

this is URL which i am loading in web view to get authorized .
I have talked with our backend team and everything seems fine from there side , any help to find out the solution would be highly appreciated .

https://localhost:9443/oauth2/authorize?client_id=[client_id]&redirect_uri=localhost:9453/commonauth&response_type=code&scope=openid

Comment: Shouldn't your authorization request to the IS be using client_id and secret of the service provider you created in IS???

Comment: No , for the first to get authcode we need only  client_id , redirect_uri response_type=code , scope=openid parameters , above problem is resolved and now i m stuck at later stage which says some problem occurred in oauth please retry

Comment: could you please guide us , we are trying google oauth , for this , we need mobile app in google developer console or web app .
as while creating mobile app , we don't get client secret from google which is required to put in identity server .

Comment: You should be using the implict grant type if you don't have access to the client_secret

Comment: "https://localhost:9443/oauth2/authorize?client_id=[client_id]&redirect_uri=localhost:9453/commonauth&response_type=token&scope=openid"

Comment: hi farasath,could we have a chat i don't think i would much help from comments

Comment: that should be fine.